# puppeteer can't click in <a> inside a <svg>, so a table should be show

Tags: node.js, web, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm web scraping a site with puppeteer, but I'm stucked in a page, where there is some charts and a value inside a svg tag, after load the value, i'd click on it to show a new box at the bottom side, where there are detailings about this value, but I can't click on it, tried everything.

the code of the click:

```html
  await page.waitFor('a[class="single-drilldown"]')
 await page.hover('text[class="single-result"]');
 await page.click('a[class="single-drilldown"]');
```

The svg block:

```html
<svg class="svg-container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 133px; width: 920px;">
<g class="single-value-main-body" data-cid="view19338" data-view="views/shared/singlevalue/MainBody" data-render-time="0.003" transform="translate(0,93.10000000000001)">
<g class="single-value-labels" data-cid="view19340" data-view="views/shared/singlevalue/Labels" data-render-time="0.002">
<g class="main-label-group"><g class="single-value-label" data-name="display.visualizations.singlevalue.singleResult" data-cid="view19342" data-view="views/shared/singlevalue/Label" data-render-time="0.002">
<g class="single-result-group">
<g class="svg-label"><a href="#" class="single-drilldown" style="text-decoration: none;">
<text class="single-result" x="386.2" style="letter-spacing: -0.02em; font-weight: bold; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51); opacity: 1; text-decoration: none; font-size: 87.78px;">262</text>
</a></g></g></g></g></g></g></svg>
```

before click:

[image: Before click]

After I click, should appers the box:

[image]

I'm sorry for few informations.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to perform a click on that a tag as you provided it   and for me it was working.

To verify that the click actually happened I added `onclick="console.log('click')"` to the a tag. After I executed the code I had it logged into the browsers console.

Maybe the click listener works somehow diffently or it's listening to another html tag I don't know.

But what you can try just to be sure is to simulate a real click on a specific position on the website. There is a function which is doing that:

`await page.mouse.click(x, y, {button: 'left'});`

Maybe that will help you.